# How to get XPath for certain values on Quora?

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a certain value from Quora and need some XPath help. In the bottom of the page, there are a number of views that I would like to obtain, but I keep getting no values.

The url is https://www.quora.com/How-much-would-it-cost-in-cloud-servers-if-I-was-expecting-10-000-000-visitors-to-a-website-within-24-hours.

These are some of the many options I've tried:

```
//div[@class='ViewsRow'][1]/text()

//*[@class='ViewsRow'][1]/text()

//div[@class='HighlightRow'][1]/text()
```

Thanks for your time and I greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you are login in Quora. so write a script which login you first in quora. Quora will not expose the views without login

Quora switching HighlightRow and ViewsRow time to time so use conatins with and so when both appears xpath will grab it

Use below xpath :-

```
//div[contains(@class,'HighlightRow') and contains(@class,'ViewsRow')]
```

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: So there is no way to do it without logging in?

Comment: Nup ... I have checked the value on DOM .. there is no sign of total values of article .. while there is views of comments present ... You can get the views of comments if you like so

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
"//div[@class='ViewsRow HighlightRow' or @class='HighlightRow ViewsRow']/text()"
```

P.S. Do not forget to login because otherwise this data is not available.

Comment: Quora is switching the both words after some time .. above xpath will be fail in that case ... See image I have shown in my answer .. you will find the words are shifted as per your xpath

Comment: Ok, thanks, didn't know they are switching, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains()` if you want to match parts of attributes.

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ViewsRow')][1]/text()
```